# Convergence of functional series $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2x)^{k}}{(1+x^{2})^{k}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

Find convergence area and absolute convergence area of the following series:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2x)^{k}}{(1+x^{2})^{k}}$$
I wrote it as 
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2x)^{k}}{(1+x^{2})^{k}}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{2x}{1+x^{2}}\right)^{k}$$
and now this is geometric series, where $q=\frac{2x}{1+x^{2}}$. So it converges absolutly when $\frac{2|x|}{1+x^{2}}<1$ and convergence area and absolute convergence area are both $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{-1, 1\}$.

Is my solution correct?

Comment: If you plug in $x=2$, you get $\frac{4}{5}<1$

Comment: Looks reasonable, but you might want to add some steps: $2|x|<1+x^2$, $0<1-2|x|+x^2$, $0<(1-|x|)^2$, $0\not=(1-|x|)^2$, $0\not=1-|x|$, $|x|\not=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is correct.  I would include additional reasoning as to how you solved the inequality to get the area of absolute convergence; e.g., $2|x|/(1+x^2) < 1$ implies $$0 < x^2 - 2|x| + 1 = (|x| - 1)^2,$$ and since such a square is only $0$ when $|x| = 1$ or $x \in \{-1,1\}$, the result follows.

Answer (score 0):

You need to solve the inequality 
$$
x^2 + 1 - 2 x >0
$$
which is true for all $x$. Now add the boundary inequalities that come from the equliaty
$$
\frac{2x}{x^2+1}=0
$$
for $x=1$ or $x=-1$